# Why the compiler do not read import addMore from '../addMore/addMore'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I would like to add a Component 'addMore'. But teh Compiler don't read this. What do I have forget? PLease Help.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { MdDeleteForever } from 'react-icons/md'
import addMore from '../addMore/addMore'
import './ShoppingCardItem.css'


export default function ShoppingCardItem() {

  return (
    <div className='shoppingCardItem-Container'>
        <img src="./img/Apfel.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>2x Apfel</p>
        <addMore />
        <MdDeleteForever />
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function addMore() {
  return (
    <div className="btn-group">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">+</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Component Name must start with `Capital Letter`. Rename you file name `addMore.jsx` to `AddMore.jsx` and also change import Path. Checkout this information checkout [React.dev Functional Component](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component#:%7E:text=React%20components%20are%20regular%20JavaScript%20functions%2C%20but%20their%20names%20must%20start%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20or%20they%20won%E2%80%99t%20work!)

```
// ShoppingCardItem.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { MdDeleteForever } from 'react-icons/md'
import AddMorefrom '../AddMore/AddMore'
import './ShoppingCardItem.css'


export default function ShoppingCardItem() {

  return (
    <div className='shoppingCardItem-Container'>
        <img src="./img/Apfel.jpg" alt="" />
        <p>2x Apfel</p>
        <AddMore/>
        <MdDeleteForever />
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// AddMore.jsx

import React from 'react'

export default function AddMore() {
  return (
    <div className="btn-group">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">+</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```